# My bot does not have time to read messages - Telegram Bot API

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I use the library Telegram.Bot for c#. I do not use webhook. The problem is this: my bot reads the chat (it seems that it checks for a certain period of time), but does not see messages that were deleted by the faster bot. As a result, my bot cannot work.
How can I manage to read messages without using a webhook?

--
Perhaps I incorrectly asked a question. The second bot is not mine, it is just in the chat, because of it my bot does not have time to receive messages, it deletes them earlier.

Comment: I believe there is an event that fires when a message is deleted. Perhaps you can use that?

Comment: No, there is no such event, the api bot does not provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use one bot, after receiving all the new messages delete them with the following method https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

Comment: Perhaps I incorrectly asked a question. The second bot is not mine, it is just in the chat, because of it my bot does not have time to receive messages, it deletes them earlier.

Comment: If you can't replace the other bot or use webhook, i don't think you can be sure that you will read all the messages